# I dont want '1' to be included next to string

Tags: php

I have this code below:
    $insert = array();

```
  for ($i = 1, $n = $_POST['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i)
  {

      if( $_POST['sessionNum'] == '1'){
            $insert[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . ($i == 1 ? '' : $i) . "'";
        }else{
            $insert[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "'";
        }


    $insert[] .= "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['textMarks'] ) . "'";
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, TotalMarks) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insert) . ")";


  mysql_query($sql);
```

What the code above does is that it adds a number next to the $_POST['id'] depending on what the number is in the $_POST['sessionNum'].

For example if  $_POST['sessionNum'] is '3'  and  $_POST['id'] is VBV, then it will display 'VBV3'.

But what I want is that if $_POST['sessionNum'] is '1', I do not want it to display 'VBV1' but instead just 'VBV' as it is a single session.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: So you *do* now how a for loop works, but you've never heard of an `if` statement?

Comment: did you actually write this code? If so, you should have an instant thought of adding an if condition before concatenating that number.

Comment: No, I did answering a previous question.

Comment: I tried if statements but they have all failed, MichaelRushton did answer this question for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1, $n = $_POST['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i)
{
  $insert[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i) . "'";
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer but it isn't quite what I meant and it was my fault because I did not mention this in question. What I want is that if there is only one session ($_POST['sessionNum'] equals 1, then display it as 'VBV', but if there are multiple sessions e.g. ($_POST['sessionNum'] equals 3, then display 'VBV1'. 'VBV2' and 'VBV3'. I have updated my code with the fialed if statement which doesn't insert the sessionId in database

Comment: Edited to reflect your clarification.

Comment: So you're aware of what's different: `($i == 1 ? '' : $i)` has been changed to `($n == 1 ? '' : $i)`.

Comment: Yes you are now saying that if sessionNum ($n) is 1, then display '' next to the id or (:) display the session number next to each session

Comment: Thank you better than the if statement I tried in code above, this has worked Thanks again :)